# Delete entire rows in struct array matlab depending on field entry

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, row, matlab-struct

I have the 1x1008 struct array EEG.event with fields

```
latency
duration
channel
bvtime
bvmknum
type
code
urevent
```

I want to delete all rows where entry in field EEG.event.type = 'boundary' or 'R  1'

I tried the following loop:

```
for b = 1:length(EEG.event)  

     if strcmp(EEG.event(b).type, 'boundary')
        EEG.event(b) = [];
     elseif strcmp(EEG.event(b).type, 'R  1')
        EEG.event(b) = [];
     end

end
```

This does not work of course, since the counting variable `b` at some point exceeds the length of `EEG.event`.

Does anyone have an idea how to delete particular rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental issue that you are having is that you are modifying the same array of structs that you are trying to loop through. This is generally a bad idea and will lead to the issue that you are seeing.

The easiest way to do this is to actually convert the `event.type` fields of all structs to a cell array, and use `strcmp` on all of them simultaneously to construct a logical matrix that you can use to index into `EEG.event` to get the entries you care about.

You can put all of the `type` values in a cell array like this

```
types = {EEG.event.type};
```

Then create your logical array by looking for event types of 'boundary'

```
isBoundary = strcmp(types, 'boundary');
```

And get the subset of `EEG.event` entries like this.

```
boundaryEvents = EEG.event(isBoundary);
```

If you want a subset of your events where the type isn't 'boundary' or 'R  1', then you can get that subset this way.

```
isBoundary = strcmp(types, 'boundary');
isR1 = strcmp(types, 'R  1');

% Keep the entries that aren't boundary or R1 types
events_to_use = EEG.event(~(isBoundary | isR1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop to iterate backward through the array, deleting elements toward the end first:

```
for b = length(EEG.event):-1:1
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers!

This straight forward line of code does the job:

```
[ EEG.event( strcmp( 'boundary', { EEG.event.type } ) | strcmp( 'R  1', { EEG.event.type } ) ) ] = [];
```

Cheers!